# Assigning save (:w<cr>) to <leader>w in vim

Tags: vim

I want to be able to save a file in vim while in the insert mode. I thought of using the following shortcut:

```
inoremap <leader>w <Esc>:w<cr>
```

While the shortcut saves the file in the insert mode, it leaves the cursor one spot ahead of where the cursor would be if I physically typed out the keys 
`Esc :w` followed by `Enter`. This is a problem because when I use the shortcut whenever I am at the end of a line, it takes me to the next line, and I have to then come back to the spot where I initiated the save.

Any help would be appreciated on how I can map `<leader>w` to the exact actions that occur in Vim when I physically type out the `Esc :w` followed by `Enter` key sequence.

I should add that if I instead use the following key-mapping, things work exactly as I want:

```
inoremap <C-s> <esc>:w<CR>
```

However, I would like to avoid pressing `CTRL` and `s` at the same time. It is possible there is some problem with the `<leader>`, but I cannot figure out what it is (I am using `,` as my leader key).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Though one could discuss the suitability of your insert-mode mapping, the root cause of your problem is a **trailing space in the mapping definition**; i.e. Vim reads this as follows:

```
inoremap <leader>w <Esc>:w<cr><Space>
```

You'll even see this in the `:imap <Leader>w` output! `<Space>` in normal mode advances the cursor one to the right (like `l`); that explains the unexpected move.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
inoremap <silent> <leader>w <C-o>:w<CR>
```

The idea is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> can be used to run commands directly from insert mode.  See `:help i_CTRL-O` for details.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply doing

```
inoremap <leader>w <Esc>h:w<cr>
```

(not the additional `h` for going back one character)?